# How to disable automatic linking in recent Mediawiki versions (1.29 and 1.30)?

Tags: configuration, mediawiki

Newer versions of Mediawiki appear to have this feature where text strings are aggressively converted to links. For example, if you put "File:Foo" on a wiki page, it will be autoconverted to a link, canonically "[[File:Foo]]" in wikitext. Similarly, a link in text (with no brackets to indicate a link) automatically gets converted to a link.

I'm looking for a configuration setting to disable this.

Due diligence - online search turned up no useful or relevant pages: https://www.bing.com/search?q=mediawiki+disable+automatic+links&pc=MOZI&form=MOZSBR

Answer (score 0):

I have not seen anything of the sort on my wiki (MediaWiki 1.27) or on Wikipedia (MediaWiki 1.32). Nothing in the [configuration settings manual](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings) seems to be able to toggle this behavior. It might be an extension causing this-you could try disabling some if you have access to your `LocalSettings.php`.

I know it's a pain, but you could enclose them in `<nowiki>` tags if nothing else works.

Comment: This answer is wrong. I tested it on multiple MW installs. 2 of them were 1.31, 1 of which was nearly vanilla and this happened. I also tested on a much older stack (MW 1.20.2) which produce the same behavior.

Comment: The `<nowiki>` approach worked for me to prevent an external URL from getting link-ified (I had specific reasons for wanting to do so)